# PHP no me reconoce las variables auxiliares

Tags: php, revisión-de-código, variables

Buenas, el problema que tengo es el siguiente: En un ejercicio me obligan a usar sólo if-else para saber cuál de los tres números es el mayor/menor.

El error está en que no me recoge las variables auxiliares, y no sé por qué:
Mi código:

**EDIT**

No puedo usar tampoco operadores como AND,NOT... etc, sólo comparando valores.

```
<?php
        //Declaración de variables que se introducen del formulario     
                $num1 = $_POST['num1'];
                $num2 = $_POST['num2'];
                $num3 = $_POST['num3'];
        //Muestra de las variables introducidas
                echo "Los números introducidos son $num1,  $num2 y $num3";
        //Condiciones del ejercicio
                if ($num1 > $num2) {
                        $aux=$num1;
                }
                        elseif ($aux > $num3  ) {
                                echo"$num1 es el mayor de todos";
                                }
                        elseif ($num1 < $num2) {
                                $aux2=$num1;
                                }
                        elseif ($aux2 < $num3) {
                                echo"$num1 es el menor de todos";
                                }
                        elseif ($num2 > $num1) {
                                $aux3=$num2;
                                }
                        elseif ($aux4 > $num3) {
                                echo"$num2 es el mayor de todos";
                                }
                        elseif ($num2 < $num1) {
                                $aux4=$num2;
                                }
                        elseif ($aux4 < $num3) {
                                echo"$num2 es el menor de todos";
                                }
                        elseif ($num3 > $num1) {
                                $aux=$num3;
                                }
                        elseif ($aux5 > $num2) {
                                echo"$num1 es el mayor de todos";
                                }
                        elseif ($num3 < $aux2) {
                                echo"$num3 es el menor de todos";
                                }
                        else {
                                echo"Todos los números son iguales";
                        }

?>
```

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar desde dónde envías esos números? Entiendo que los envías de un formulario.

Comment: en tu codigo no veo donde declaras las variables auxiliares

Comment: Las variables auxiliares son $AUX

Comment: Si, pero por que dices $num1 = $aux? Donde esta el valor de $aux? donde la declaras? a que valor reemplazas el valor de $num1?

Comment: quiero asigar $num1 a $aux Lamento que haya creado confusión, soy bastante noob en esto de PHP y programación en general.

Comment: entonces es $aux = $num1

Comment: He modificado el código como me indicas, pero me da problemas esta vez con los if, que no me muestran las variables. ¿Debo hacerlas globales?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47177/discussion-between-sioesi-and-ras212).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las variables auxiliares son para guardar datos que necesitamos pero que después sabemos que pueden cambiar. Como tus valores no cambian si no que se comparan con otros números, solo debes comparar los números unos con otros y encontrar el mayor y el menor.

Un caso muy sencillo es cuando quieres intercambiar valores entre dos variables ej :

```
$numero_uno = 1;
$numero_dos = 2;
```

¿Como los cambio?

```
$numero_auxiliar = $numero_uno;
$numero_uno = $numero_dos;
$numero_dos = $numero_auxiliar;
```

Ejemplo :

```
<?php
        $numero_uno = 1;
        $numero_dos = 2;
        echo "numero uno ".$numero_uno;
        echo "<br><br>";
        echo "numero dos ".$numero_dos;
        echo "<br><br>";
        $numero_auxiliar = $numero_uno;
        $numero_uno = $numero_dos;
        $numero_dos = $numero_auxiliar;
        echo "<br><br>";
        echo "numero uno ".$numero_uno;
        echo "<br><br>";
        echo "numero dos ".$numero_dos;
 ?>
```

Entonces para resolver tu problema bastaria asi , reemplaza los valores de los `$num1`, `$num2` y `$num3` por los valores `$_POST` que quieres.

```
<?php
    $num1 = 54;
    $num2 = 6;
    $num3 = 6;
    $mayor = 0;
    $menor = 0;

    if($num1 > $num2){
            if($num1 > $num3){
                    $mayor = $num1;
            }else{
                    $mayor = $num3;
            }
    }else{
            if($num2 > $num3){
                    $mayor = $num2;
            }else{
                    $mayor = $num3;
            }
    }
    if($num1 < $num2){
            if($num1 < $num3){
                    $menor = $num1;
            }else{
                    $menor = $num3;
            }
    }else{
            if($num2 < $num3){
                    $menor = $num2;
            }else{
                    $menor = $num3;
            }
    }
    if($menor == $mayor){
            echo "los numeros son iguales";
    }else{
            echo "El numero mayor es $mayor";
            echo "<br><br>";
            echo "El numero menor es $menor";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Realmente si no sabemos como pasa los datos, es imposible saber porque no le llegan al fichero. Yo supongo que estará mal el formulario o el acceso al fichero. Sin embargo, hasta que no edite la pregunta todo serán suposiciones.

Comment: Exacto!, al postear el codigo, asumo que sus valores SI llegan por $_POST a sus valores $num1, $num2 y $num3 pero no a las variables aux. Yo no las veo declaradas, pero pienso que para este ejercicio no es necesario.. por eso aporte esta respuesta

Comment: de hecho if ($num1 > $num2) { $num1=$aux;} eso ya es raro, mi respuesta lo ayuda a eliminar esa variable auxiliar y obtener lo que el realmente busca. Asigna un valor que no existe o no esta definido, de ahi para abajo el problema

Comment: Yo la verdad que por variables auxiliares había entendido a las que no estaban dentro del fichero (las variables que vienen por $_POST). Esperaremos a ver si edita la pregunta para salir de dudas :D

Comment: Y como sabes que no importan las variables aux?

Comment: Porque leyendo el codigo el las utiliza para guardar los valores que se ingresaron en el formulario y las compara hasta encontrar el numero mayor e imprimirlo, en este ejemplo estan demas.

Comment: Lo que está haciendo el OP es lo contrario... `$num1 = $aux` es decir, asigna posteriormente las variables `$num` por las variables `$aux`... entonces no queda claro de donde viene... para que sirven y etc etc...

Comment: Eso es lo que no me queda claro,  de donde sale ese valor $aux, si no actualiza la pregunta el Op borrare mi respuesta ya que hasta ahora no responde a su necesidad. Si para el las variables aux viendo mi ejemplo son innecesarias, la dejare.  Saludos y gravias por ayudarme!

Comment: Las variables aux son para que cuando se cumpla la condición inicial de que un número es mayor que otro

Comment: @ras212 tu tienes `if ($num1 > $num2) { $num1=$aux; }` Se lee : Si numero 1 es mayor a numero2 entonces numero 1 es igual a auxiliar... QUE TIENE AUXILIAR?

Comment: Solucionado, muchísimas gracias

Comment: @ras212 De nada! y para otra pregunta que quieras hacer, sé mas claro, deja todas las opciones que pueda tener y tambien las restricciones!, Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$num1 = $_POST['num1'];
$num2 = $_POST['num2'];
$num3 = $_POST['num3'];

$max = $num1;
$min = $num2;

if($num2 > $max) {
    $max = $num2;
    $min = $num1;
} elseif($num3 > $max) {
    $max = $num3;
} elseif ($num3 < $min) {
    $min = $num3;
}

if ($num1 == $num2 && $num1 == $num3) {
    echo "Todos los números son iguales";
} elseif {
    echo "El $max es el número más grande";
    echo "El $min es el número más pequeño";
}
?>
```